# Convert an expression tree back to string form using only depth first and/or breadth first traversal

Tags: matlab, tree, expression-trees, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm working on a genetic programming problem that involves an expression tree. The tree data structure I'm using provides only accessors in terms of depth first and breadth first traversal. What's an efficient way for me to recover an expression from the tree using only these provided methods?

Comment: Does it offer pre-order, in-order, post-order versions of DFS? DFS is fine, but having pre-order or post-order would make it much easier than if it only has pre-order.

Comment: What is the exact interface that you can use to traverse the data structure?

Comment: It's in preorder form. Basically I can call a function to do a DFS or BFS and a list of the nodes visited is returned in pre-order form.

Comment: What is the interface, do you get the number of subnodes for each one of the nodes?

Comment: No, only the value of the nodes. No information on the subnodes. I am however able to access an array that has information on the parent of each node.

Comment: If you have a way of going from a node to it's parents, then it becomes simple from the algorithmic perspective. Use the references to the parents to generate the levels, and BFS to provide a left-to-right ordering on elements at the same level

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved by using a recursive BFS search. Basically the function calls itself on the subtrees unless the subtree is a terminal node, in which case the value of the node is returned.